# nth-child ul list item background repeating to sub ul lists

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-selectors

I'm busy with the design of a Bigcommerce website and have found a css syntax problem with list items and their respective backgrounds.

The List item headings and the list items themselves are generated from a database. Here's what my code looks like :

```
.Left #SideCategoryList ul li:first-child a {
background-image:url("hiddenurl/product_images/uploaded_images/cat-types.png") !important;
padding-left:10px;
padding-top:25px;    
}

.Left #SideCategoryList ul li:nth-child(2) a {
 background-image:url("hiddenurl/product_images/uploaded_images/cat-collections.png") !important;
padding-left:10px;
padding-top:36px;
}
.Left #SideCategoryList ul li:nth-child(3) a {
background-image:url("hiddenurl/product_images/uploaded_images/cat-themes.png") !important;
padding-left:10px;
padding-top:17px;
}
```

These images display perfectly as the headers' backgrounds of my list items.

However these backgrounds are then added to the subsequent ul list items which I cant seem to remove.

I have tried to force the subsequent list items to have no background with the following:

```
.Left #SideCategoryList ul li ul li a {
background-image:none !important;
}
```

But they still won't go away.

Do you guys have any Idea how I can either recode the list item's backgrounds or to force the rest of the list items so these backgrounds only appear on the "outer" Ul's list item headings?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**  I'm removing my url for privacy concerns. The full http:\ url is in the original css.

**Edit 2** For Clarity, the lists structures are laid out like this :

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
    <li> 
       <ul>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
      <ul>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you jsfiddle it? you can use an image hosting site to host your images, that way we can see exactly what you're looking at in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

try this selector for your css:-

```
.Left #SideCategoryList > ul > li:first-child > a
```

'>' indicates immediate child so internal Ul,Li will not get affected